# message pip tail on div in css

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, styled-components, pseudo-element

I am trying to create this style directly through CSS. I have the whole button figured out except the tail on the top left corner. How do I add that through CSS? Here is what I want it to look like;

[image]

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo css/html elements for this

:before and :after

See this hyperlink for a fuller understanding https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

Basically the opening paragrap states

> The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements in CSS allows you to insert content onto a page without it needing to be in the HTML. While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is, and would essentially be like this:

```
div::before {
  content: "before";
}
div::after {
  content: "after";
}
```

this makes your HTML have *fake* **elements that can be styled** in the HTML

```
<div>
  before
  <!-- Rest of stuff inside the div -->
  after
</div>
```

You can use the *border* css attribute on the **:before** pseudo element

HTML example
** DISCLAIMER ** the following CSS was borrowed from Code Pen https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/QpYqMW and this user [rajeshdn](https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn) deserves the credit

```
<div class="speechBubble">
  Will do!
</div>

.speechBubble {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #888;}

.speechBubble:before {
content: "";
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
position: absolute;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
border-right: 15px solid #888; // medium grey
border-top: 15px solid #888;
border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
left: -16px;
top: 0px;}
```

```css
  .speechBubble {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #888;
    width: 25%}

    .speechBubble:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #888; // medium grey
    border-top: 15px solid #888;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    left: -16px;
    top: 8px;}
```

```html
<div class="speechBubble">
  Will do!
</div>
```

**How** does it work

By using the `border` and `position` property and clever use of `color` (or colour if your British but that doesn't work in HTML/Web design - have to use the American spelling)

- every (most) HTML elements can have a border - even pseudo (fake) elements
- the position attribute is set to 'absolute' [see css positioning](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)
- it is postioned or steered into position  using the top and left attributes *(I use trial and error to get the right location though smarter people probably calculate the positioning)*
- as each element has 4 borders: *top, right, left, bottom* you have to manipulate them so the result ends up looking like a triangle using color and transparency *(set the color to the same background coolor as your main speech bubble)*

It takes (me anyway) a bit of time to get these things looking perfect and sometimes there are cross browser or device issues (PCs, phones, tablets etc) so sometimes a small effect can require **heaps** of work